# How can I set orientation to landscape in mobile REACT JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvas, rotation, signaturepad

I have a canvas in my project where you can draw a signature and save it. I'm using **React JS** and https://github.com/szimek/signature_pad which is great. But the problem i have is that i need to set the default orientation to landscape on mobile (*I dont want to display a message like 'please use landscape' and then show the canvas*).

If i rotate the canvas with something like: div.style.webkitTransform = 'rotate(90deg)';
visually it looks good, the problem is that when I draw a line to the right it goes down, if I draw a line to the left it goes up, etc (as if the canvas is in the original 0°)

Is there a way to change the **orientation** of canvas in anyway?

I found some library which was able in React Native only, tried to find a workaround with css and using [The Screen Orientation API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS_Object_Model/Managing_screen_orientation) but nothing seems to work